# Shortest distance from point to edge of image

Tags: canvas, shortest-path

This is probably addressed elsewhere, but I can't find anything on it. I'm trying to find the shortest distance between an arbitrary point on an image and the nearest transparent pixel with a greater emphasis on speed than accuracy.

Currently what I'm doing is checking each pixel in a line for every 0.1 radians, stopping when it reaches a transparent pixel and keeping track of the shortest. That's not particularly fast or accurate though. Is there a better way? Maybe an algorithm people use for this sort of thing?

I'm doing this with javascript/canvas.

Comment: is the image rectangular (i.e. no transparent regions)?

Comment: no, it's an figure on a transparent background. Essentially, it can be thought of as a binary image since all I'm looking for is transparent/not transparent.

Comment: What is your metric for acceptable accuracy?  for example suppose there is a single transparent pixel right next to the point of origin and you don't test it.  Is it acceptable to return a transparent point that is on the other edge of the picture?

Comment: @ajon that would be acceptable to miss one or two transparent pixels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is to calculate the distance for all pixels to the nearest transparent pixel [(distance transform)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_transform), which can be performed in two passes of the original image.
When the distance transform have been calculated, the nearest transparent pixel can be found in constant time, O(1).
This approach is superior if the transparent area is changing slowly over time.

In the case where the transparent area is changing fast, you can probably do better.

Comment: That looks pretty promising since the image actually isn't changing at all, just the points to measure from are. However it seems like it would be quite expensive on the outset, is that the case or am I not understanding it correctly?

Comment: Actually, I think I've come up with a good way to implement that, let me try it out and I'll post the results.

Comment: Unfortunately, the example kind of sucks because I can't figure out how to use any other image but the jsfiddle logo due to cross-origin security, but this works great. Thanks http://jsfiddle.net/rcfWw/1/

Answer (score 0):

The fastest accurate algorithm is to simply do circles around the point.  Check every adjacent pixel, then check the next layer, essentially a breadth-first search, and that will run in O(n) time where n is the number of pixels.  Now what you are doing is a faster probabilistic approach.

The only way I can think to make an algorithm faster than yours is to pick a circle size, say 3 pixel diameter, and check (for example) 75% (The optimal percentage depends on your desire for accuracy) of the pixels on that circle. If you don't find a transparent pixel, then double the size of your circle.  Depending on what the image looks like though, this may be very inaccurate, but it prefers speed to accuracy.

Otherwise, I don't really see an improvement to your algorithm unless you can collect data about where a transparent pixel is based on the pixels around it.  Then you can be a little smarter with the search.  Otherwise all you learn by testing a pixel is that one and only pixel is (or is not) transparent.

If you can say that you are only looking for transparent regions larger than x pixels and you want to accurately find any region that is x pixels in diameter then you can adjust the sizes of your circles to grow by x-1, then to improve accuracy you can follow the transparent pixels toward your point of origin until you find the closest pixel.